# Weird Output in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am using the terminal for some debugging and I noticed that it has stopped displaying my user before the path. Now its displaying (null) like so:

```
(null):mspgcc-examples dean$
```

Whats changed? As i've changed no configuration to change it. Viewing the shell variable `$PS1` I get the following results:

```
(null):mspgcc-examples dean$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$
(null):mspgcc-examples dean$
```

Comment: please, provide your $PS1 value

Comment: Is `$PS1` a shell variable?

Comment: Yes, use `echo $PS1` to display its value. Also: try to open a new tab in Terminal (with Cmd-T) and check the prompt there.

Comment: And please check whether http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43063/mac-terminal-shows-null-for-host-name-at-the-prompt solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can read through the [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3415242?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple Discussion Group for details. The most important that some routers doesn't like computer names which can't be part of valid DNS name (English letters, numbers, dashes, underscores).

To name my Mac I use something like `Eir-Mac` or `EirMac` and have no problems.